# Patroni Timeout Error - ConnectTimeoutError

Tags: postgresql, haproxy, high-availability, etcd, patroni

I tried to install Postgresql HA Cluster Setup with Patroni but all organizations
after completion I got errors on my patroni and postgresql nodes.
I checked the error logs and saw that the servers could not connect to my etcd server.

config;

node1   patroni,postgresql  192.168.1.15
node2   patroni,postgresql  192.168.1.16
node3   etcd            192.168.1.17
node4   HAProxy         192.168.1.18

- node1 /etc/patroni.yml;

```
scope: patroni_deneme
namespace: /db/
name: master

restapi:
    listen: 192.168.1.15:8008
    connect_address: 192.168.1.15:8008

etcd:
    host: 192.168.1.17:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 192.168.1.15/0 md5
    - host replication replicator 192.168.1.16/0 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: 192.168.1.15:5433
    connect_address: 192.168.1.15:5433
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: sifre123
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: sifre123
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

- node2 /etc/patroni.yml;

```
scope: patroni_deneme
namespace: /db/
name: master

restapi:
    listen: 192.168.1.16:8008
    connect_address: 192.168.1.16:8008

etcd:
    host: 192.168.1.17:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication replicator 192.168.1.15/0 md5
    - host replication replicator 192.168.1.16/0 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb

postgresql:
    listen: 192.168.1.16:5433
    connect_address: 192.168.1.16:5433
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: sifre123
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: sifre123
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
```

- node3 /etc/default/etcd;

```
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://192.168.1.17:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379,http://192.168.1.17:2379"
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://192.168.1.17:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="default=http://192.168.1.17:2380"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://192.168.1.17:2379"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-cluster"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
```

- node4 /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg;

```
global
    maxconn 100

defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    retries 2
    timeout client 30m
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30m
    timeout check 5s

listen stats
    mode http
    bind *:7000
    stats enable
    stats uri /

listen postgres
    bind *:5000
    option httpchk
    http-check expect status 200
    default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
    server PSQL01 192.168.1.15:5433 maxconn 100 check port 8008
    server PSQL02 192.166.1.16:5433 maxconn 100 check port 8008
```

Error Log;

```
Jan 02 12:08:38 master patroni[14341]: 2024-01-02 12:08:38,970 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f88825e6940>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.17 timed out. (connect timeout=1.6666666666666667)')': /v2/machines
Jan 02 12:08:40 master patroni[14341]: 2024-01-02 12:08:40,414 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f88825ab730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host')': /v2/machines
Jan 02 12:08:42 master patroni[14341]: 2024-01-02 12:08:42,084 ERROR: Failed to get list of machines from http://192.168.1.17:2379/v2: MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.17', port=2379): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/machines (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f88825ab700>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.17 timed out. (connect timeout=1.6666666666666667)'))")
Jan 02 12:08:42 master patroni[14341]: 2024-01-02 12:08:42,084 INFO: waiting on etcd
```

I checked the configuration on the etcd node but all the information is correct.
I also rechecked the info of the etcd node in the config file of the patroni nodes and didn't see anything wrong.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find the source of the problem.